# Spire.PDF Load Binary PDF Data into PdfDocument

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, binary-data, pdf-conversion

I'm working in C# with [Spire.PDF](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html#.Vg1ncSuA9-I). Specifically, my goal is to load binary PDF data from a database into a `Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument` object.

According to this [documentation](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Save-PDF-file-to-Stream-and-Load-PDF-file-from-Stream-in-C-.NET.html), I should be able to use the `LoadFromStream()` method or some unspecified method that takes a byte array (see bottom of page at link where there is a link but only to the general documentation). However, this method seems absent from the current NuGet package.

So, in summary, how can I make a `Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument` object using a byte array of data? Thanks in advance.

Please comment if you know a better .NET library for converting PDFs to and from images.

Comment: I just downloaded the most recent version (3.5.51.5040) from NuGet and I can both create a `PdfDocument` via the constructor from a stream as well as call `LoadFromStream()` on a previously created `PdfDocument` instance.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using the free version, which is at 3.20. I'll give the unfree version a try.

Comment: @ChrisHaas So yeah, it works with the nonfree/evaluation version. That's unfortunate. Wonder if those changes will trickle to the free library soon. I posted a question on their forums.

Comment: There seem to be limitations imposed on the free version. I am using 3.8.45 and cannot use SaveToStream with the SVG file format: The memorystream is empty. But if I use SaveToStream with PDF file format, or SaveToFile with SVG file format, it works fine.